# Figure out whether a function has return value of not?

Tags: binary-analysis, static-analysis, elf, functions, x86-64

I am doing binary analysis on `x86-64bit` ELF binaries. All the binaries are compiled from `C` language. Basically, for a given function, I would like to figure out whether this function has a return value or not. That is, in its corresponding `C` code, whether a meaningful `return` exists.

As I am essentially facing the assembly code, it is not feasible to figure out through some type information. However, as for normal `x86-64bit` assembly program, the calling convention only allows register `rax` to hold the return value, **so I am thinking to check the usage of `rax` after a typical function call and decide whether the target function returns a value.**

Here is an example in `AT&T` syntax:

```
foo:
   ...
   call bar
   mov 0, %rax  <--- bar should not have a return value

bar:
   ...
```

In the above example, as `rax` is immediately reset, it is unlikely for function `bar` to return a value.

Another example:

```
foo:
   ...
   call bar
   jmp *%rax  <----- It is very likely that bar has a return value
```

For the above case, I suppose without some aggressive inter-procedure optimization, we can say it for sure that `bar` returns a value (a pointer).

I think this is yet another (ad-hoc) reverse engineering task, but I guess there may be a more "formal" way to solve it, any idea on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several problems with that approach:

- Functions that return double values don't use `eax`
- Functions that return structs don't neccesarily use `eax`, see [here](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2012/02/describing-the-msvc-abi-for-structure-return-types/)
- return values from many functions, like `free`, `close`, `printf` are custumarily ignored, so "caller does not read `eax`" does not translate to "function has no return value"
- there are edge cases to "`eax` is used". For example, `xor [location], eax` probably means `eax` has a value, `xor eax, [location]` as well, but `xor eax, eax` means *probably* not.

In the generic case, i think there's no foolproof way. For example, in a function ending in

```
for (i=0; i<somevar; i++)
    somearray[i]=0;
return i;
```

the compiler may just decide to use `eax` for the loop counter; which means there's no reason to do another `mov` after the loop. If the caller ignores the value of `eax`, you have no way to determine, from the assembly alone, if that `return` statement was present or not. (Of course, in this particular case, any self respecting compiler will generate a variant of `rep stosw` or `sse` instructions, but you get the point).

So when the caller *does* read `eax`, you can be quite certain that the function has a return value; but a caller that ignores `eax` basically means nothing.

And even if the caller reads `eax`, you could construct pathological cases of a function written in assembler, that preserves `eax`, and a caller that knows about this and makes use of `eax` even over the function call. But you'll probably not encounter this in software that isn't deliberately obfuscated

Comment: Thank you Guntram. This is a fantastic answer. I learned a lot from it! I guess I will start from checking the usage of `eax`. Although when considering potential control flow transfer following the `call` instruction, tracing the usage of `eax` is by no means as easy as it looks...

Comment: As I want to implement it like a dataflow analysis task.

Answer (score 0):

The return value is defined by the calling convention used by your compiler, and it usually just means "the value of `eax`/`rax`".

In your first example, `rax` is not reset, it's just set to the value `0`, hence the functions most likely ends with a `return 0;`.

In your second example, you should check what is the last write on `rax` in the `bar` function.

You could try to check whether the next operation on `rax` after your function is a write or a read, basically if it's a read the return value is used, if it's a write the return value is discarded.

Comment: "You could try to check whether the next operation on rax after your function is a write or a read" - that's what he's doing. The first example has a write to `rax` after the call to `bar`, the second example reads `rax`.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm. Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, that's basically what I am thinking to do right now ;)